# Como actualizar application.properties en tiempo de ejecucion SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un requerimiento en una API que escribi en Spring Boot, donde necesito leer un id desde el application.properties del proyecto y hacer unas query a la base de datos donde el ultimo campo que tenga esta query es el nuevo ID que necesito poner en el application.properties.

Ya busque la forma de actualizar esto en tiempo de ejecucion pero no encuentro nada en la documentacion.

Comment: Este tutorial promete hacer eso que quieres, cambiar valores en el application.properties: http://jeroenbellen.com/manage-and-reload-spring-application-properties-on-the-fly/ No lo he leído pero por favor dinos si funciona

Comment: Hasta donde lei el cliente cloud de spring exterioriza el properties para administrar sistemas distribuidos, a mi me piden cambiarlo interno sin sacar nada ademas de justificar si agrego otra dependencia al proyecto.

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez Aunque si tienes otra opcion mejor la puedo justificar, creo que me cerre mucho al requerimiento y no me deja ver mas alla :P

Comment: Puedes cargar el archivo en un objeto Properties por medio del método **load**, alterar el valor con **setProperty** y luego guardar el archivo modificado con **store**. Lo anterior implica que conozcas la ubicación exacta del archivo.

Comment: Usa spring cloud config, esto te permite tener tus properties en un repositorio git o SVN, y poder actualizarlo facilmente;